# Execute package task with external reference to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2017

** Edit: Executing the package with T-SQL script causes an authentication problem:
"Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'." **

** Edit 2: This error is caused by Windows credentials performing a double hop. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652568/ssis-job-fails-when-run-remotely-thru-ssms-but-runs-fine-on-sql-server) is a solution to this problem **

I'm trying to execute an SSIS package that was already deployed to an SQL Server instance before. This SQL Server instance's version is 14.0.3281 (SQL Server 2017).

I can't use project reference as the wanted package is in another project, and I prefer not to upload it to the server's file system.

Is it really a version problem?
How can I execute a deployed package from another project?

I know I can run the a job with this package with T-SQL, but I want the task to continue only after this package has successfully completed its execution.

This is the error I get:

> The attempted operation is not supported with this database version.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The attempted operation is not supported with this database version.

[image: Visual Studio Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to run a package via T-SQL and wait for it to finish using built-in procedures.

```
-- Create the execution object
DECLARE @execution_id BIGINT
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
    @package_name = @PackageName
    , @project_name = @ProjectName
    , @folder_name = @FolderName
    , @use32bitruntime = False
    , @reference_id = NULL
    , @execution_id = @execution_id OUTPUT

-- Configure execution
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
    @execution_id
    , @object_type = 50 -- System parameter
    , @parameter_name = N'SYNCHRONIZED'
    , @parameter_value = 1 -- set this to 1 to wait for completion

-- Start the execution
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
```

You could wrap this into a stored procedure like "startPackage" and also include checking for the result using the execution id:

```
-- Check package status, and fail script if the package failed
IF 7 <> (SELECT [status] FROM [SSISDB].[catalog].[executions] WHERE execution_id = @execution_id) AND @Syncronized = 1
        RAISERROR('The package failed!', 16, 1)
```

Comment: I tried your solution, and there is a problem with it.
The package can be executed successfully with a proxy account, using SQL Server Job Agent, and it authenticates to SQL Server with this account. When I try to execute the package with this script, logged in with the same account executing the job, I get this error:
 
SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error Code: 0x80040E4D. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description:" Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.".

Comment: What we usually do is use SSIS to execute a deployed SSIS package much like you would use an "Execute package" Task only instead it is a TSQL-Task with this script. It will run with the user set in SQL Server Agent.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that you can't delegate your credentials more than one hop with Windows Authentication. So if your package is on another server as your client and the database is on a third server, it will fallback to NT AUTHORITY.

Comment: It is a delegation problem which is now being solved with Kerberos.
I can't use the Execute Package task with external reference, this was the first thing I tried and the reason I asked here for the first time. 
So it's not an SSIS Problem anymore, and your answer did help me. Thank you!